# Tooltip left arrow can't change color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a tooltip with data-placement right:

```
<i
    class="fas fa-question-circle text-blue"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    data-placement="right"
    title="hello"
></i>
```

I am trying to change the tooltip arrow color like so:

```
.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
  border-left-color: red !important;
}
```

But nothing happens unfortunately, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color is changed above '::before'

```
.bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^=right] .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-right .arrow::before{
  right: 0;
  border-width: .4rem .4rem .4rem 0;
  border-right-color: red;
}
```

Teach you a way to review elements.

[image]